# Is lapack getri numerically the same as getrs with identity matrix as RHS?

Tags: numerical-analysis, linear-solver, lapack

I was just wondering, in case of computing `B=inv(A)`, suppose `I` is the identity matrix (diagonal),

After obtaining the factorization `A_factorization` by computing `getrf(A)`, is it numerically the same to do the following solving steps?

```
getrs(A_factorization, piv, I)
getri(A_factorization, piv)
```

Comment: As usual, the most important question is whether you need the inverse or not.

Comment: Have you tried it? Are the results exactly equal floating point numbers?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In my calculation they give the same result, but I guess it's not true in general, that's the reason I ask this question, hopefully someone will clarify the theory behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I LAPACK [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga56d9c860ce4ce42ded7f914fdb0683ff.html#ga56d9c860ce4ce42ded7f914fdb0683ff) it states for `getri`

> This method inverts U and then computes inv(A) by solving the system
>    inv(A)*L = inv(U) for inv(A).

It seems that numerically is a different procedure than solving `L*inv(L)=I` and then `U*inv(A)=inv(L)`. My understanding is that `getri` should be faster than `getrs`. Otherwise it would be no reason of creating this, except maybe of saving some memory work space.

Of course result is same in both cases.

Comment: "Of course result is same in both cases,"  Why is that true, given that calculations are performed in double precision, not infinite precision?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you have a point, maybe "acceptable" would be better. But my feeling is that it might be misleading